# PWM signal generation based on Mic input

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pwm, adc

I am using MPC 7555 controller. It has a 16 bit sigma delta ADC. 
A signal called mic input is fed to this ADC pin. based upon the voltage , a PWM signal of same frequency of ADC signal sampling should be generated.

```
For e.g.
0.1 V  = 2 percent
0.2 V  = 4 percent
0.3 V  = 6 percent....and so on

So, i thought the following logic - 
5V -  0xFFFF in digital
0.1V - 1310
0.2V - 2620 and so on
```

So, dividing the digital value by 655 will give exact duty cycle value

```
1310/655 = 2
2620/655 = 4........
```

But digital pin could also show value of 1309 for 0.1 V which when divided by 655 would yield 1 and not 2.

Anyway i can avoid this or does any have a better solution, please share.

Comment: guys any help, please

Comment: Patience - not everyone in the world is in your time zone, 24 hours would be a good time to wait before wondering why you had no answer, and even then you should consider whether your question needs improving rather then pleading for a response.  Only those who have edited your question or already commented on it are likely to get notification of your comment in any case,

Answer (score 0):

The task is to output PWM at the same rate as the ADC conversion rate.

Suppose the ADC conversion time is T (you can establish this by reading a free-run timer counter). And suppose the ADC conversion value is V. Then the PWM output time `H` spent "high" must be

```
H = T * V / 0xFFFF
```

Every time an ADC conversion is available, you (cancel any pending one-shot timer interrupt and) set the PWM output to 1 and trigger a one-shot timer at time `H`. When it interrupts, you set the PWM output to 0 (or the other way round if you have inverse logic).

If the input is `0x0000` or `0xFFFF` you can employ an alternative strategy - set the output to 0 or 1, but don't deploy the one-shot timer.

Comment: thnaks a lot fo your answer

Comment: i m relatively new to this. pls let me know why one shot timer settings have to be done. would really appreciate it

Comment: @gabbar perhaps your controller has a PWM output feature - I didn't look. My remark was when using a controller that does not. Then you need a method of changing the output at the right moment in the duty cycle, which will be different with each (varying) reading.

Answer (score 0):

To get the best fidelity in teh PWM signal, you would do better to work directly at the resolution of the PWM rather then calculate a percentage only to then convert that to a PWM count.  Using integer percentage, you are effectively limiting your resolution to 6.64 bits per sample (i.e. log<sub>10</sub>(100)/log<sub>10</sub>(2)).

So let's say your PWM count per cycle is PWM_MAX, and your ADC maximum ADC_MAX, then the PWM high period would be:

```
pwm_high = adc_val * PWM_MAX / ADC_MAX ;
```

It is important to perform the multiplication first to avoid loss of information.  If PWM_MAX is suficiently high, there is probably no need to worry about integer division rounding toward zero rather then to teh nearest integer, but if that is a concern (for low PWM_MAX ) then:

```
pwm_high = ((adc_val * PWM_MAX) + (ADC_MAX / 2)) / ADC_MAX ;
```

For example, soy your PWM_MAX is only 100 (i.e. the resolution truely is in integer percent), then in the first case:

`pwm_high` = 1310 * 100 / 0xFFFF = 1

and in the second:

`pwm_high` = ((1310 * 100) + 0x7FFF) / 0xFFFF = 2

However if PWM_MAX is a more suitable 4096 perhaps, then:

`pwm_high` = 1310 * 4096 / 0xFFFF = 81

or

`pwm_high` = ((1310 * 4096) + 0x7fff) / 0xFFFF = 82

With PWM_MAX at 4096 you have effectively 12 bits of resolution and will maintain much higher fidelity as well as directly calculating the correct PWM value.

Comment: thanks clifford for your answer , really appreciate it. in my case for 100 percent duty cycle value to be fed to hw register is 0x8000 and adc is 15 bit and not 16 as mentioned above. so as proposed by you first slution would be fine. that is if recieved digital value is a then duty  = (a * 0x8000)/0x7FFF. pls correct if i am wrong

Comment: @gabbar : The question actually specifies a 16 bit ADC, but no matter. Many ADC have an option to shift the result left so that the MSB is 0x8000. This allows the code to be written for 16 bit regardless of the actual ADC resolution,making the code more portable. You can apply the shift in software for hardware that does not support it.